# Luke Skywalker's life on Tatooine

Tags: star-wars

Are there any books or comics that give us more information about Luke's early life, between arriving at Tatooine and leaving with Obi-Wan?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being closed under "lists and recommendations". The question isn't which you should read, it's whether such a thing exists.

Comment: @Richard If the question was really just "does it exist", then your answer could/should have just been "yes." The nature of these questions, however, really requires some examples (a list of recommendations, if you will), at the very least, of stories that go into the timeframe.

Comment: @phantom42 - It's certainly a finite list (three books, two comics) and he's not asking which he should read, just whether any of the comics/novels cover it. I don't think this fits the criteria for a Vote-to-close:List

Comment: @Richard I'd generally agree, and that's why I didn't personally VTC this time - but the argument is generally a valid one. Also, Lil Trevis *did* ask for a "good book". *You* updated the question to ask for *any* book(s), which sort of contradicts your point about him not asking for recommendations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Luke's life on Tatooine, including the raging excitement of trying to fix 'vaporators with a faulty droid, sandstorms, trying to buy power convertors and his bizarre nickname (wormie) are all covered in the [deleted scenes](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xs9sum_star-wars-episode-iv-deleted-scenes-luke-biggs_shortfilms) from Star Wars IV : A New Hope.

You might also be interested in the [Star Wars Radio Plays](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEPba_tdFbk) which covers much of the same material.

---

If you're dead set on reading, these events are covered in the original [novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(novel)) and in much greater detail in the [Radio Plays collected scripts](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_National_Public_Radio_Dramatization) as well as the original Marvel [comic adaptation of A New Hope](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_(Marvel)).

- [Star Wars Tales #15](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Tales)" ([Sandstorm](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sandstorm_(comic))) details a story about 10 year old Luke. Knocked unconscious in a sandstorm, he encounters a young boy named Ani. Together they face a Krayt dragon.
- [Star Wars #17 (Crucible](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_17:_Crucible)) features a flashback to Luke's youth. Highlights include Luke, Biggs and Deak piloting their T-16 Skyhoppers through Beggar's Canyon at high speed.
- [Adventure in Beggar's Canyon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Adventure_in_Beggar%27s_Canyon) is a children's paperback. The main plot is that a young (14 year old) Luke and his friend Windy who crash their T-16 skyhoppers while attempting to "womp rats at Beggar's Canyon". Again they're saved by Ben Kenobi.
- [Old Wounds](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Old_Wounds) is a non-canon comic in which Uncle Owen and a very young Luke are threatened by a revived Darth Maul in order to draw out Obi Wan. Because of this experience, Owen tells Obi Wan to stay away from Luke and his family.

Comment: There were a few other stories in Tales that covered the time period as well. And IIRC in 'Sandstorm' it was actually a young Anakin (pre-Ep1) that helped Luke.

Comment: @Omegacron - Richard is somewhat morally opposed to things that Mickey Mouse didn't bless :)

Comment: @Omegacron - Yes, I've read it since and updated the description.

Comment: Here is another one which I remember reading a long time ago: [Star Wars #17: Crucible](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_17:_Crucible)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer - A good find. I completely forgot about that. Cheerfully added.